# Unsafe Script Replacement

Tags: javascript, toggle

I've been using a basic toggle script for some coding, but whenever I look at the page, Google Chrome tells me that the script is unsafe, so I always have to load it in manually for it to work.

Considering my Javascript skills are worse than terrible, I was wondering if anyone knew of another script that fulfilled the same thing as this one.

Basically, all it does is open up a question for a FAQ when you click, and then if you click it again, it closes.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $(".answer").hide(); 
   //toggle the componenet with class msg_body 
   $(".question").click(function() 
{ 
    $(this).next(".answer").slideToggle(600); 
});}); 
</script>
```

Comment: That message is about scripts that you load from a server URL, not about inline scripts.

Comment: It happens if you load your page from an `https:` URL, but it tries to load other scripts from `http:` URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message has nothing to do with the script you showed. It means you loaded your page with HTTPS, but it tried to load other scripts using HTTP. Change your `<script>` tags so they omit the protocol. So if you have any lines like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you should change them all to:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So sorry to ask another question, but how would I do that? Just insert my script between ...min.js"> and </script>?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your script. You're supposed to change the line that says `<script src="http://whatever">` to `<script src="//whatever">`